# Getting bus error when composing a lot of images with sharp

Tags: node.js, sharp, vips

I'm trying to compose a ton of images (2300) into a transparent png using `sharp`. I'm trying that with the following code:

```js
await sharp({
    create: {
      width: 256,
      height: 256,
      channels: 4,
      background: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, alpha: 0 },
    },
  })
    .composite(images)
    .png()
    .toBuffer();
```

Where `images` is an array generated like this:

```js
const pinSvg = fs.readFileSync("./icon_web_pin_record_basic.svg");
const pinWidth = 18;
const pinHeight = 25;
const generateImageFromLocationArray = (locations) => {
  const images = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    const [x, y] = locations[i];
    images.push({
      input: pinSvg,
      blend: "add",
      left: x - Math.floor(pinWidth / 2),
      top: y - pinHeight,
    });
  }
  return images;
};
```

With a few images, everything works fine, but with 2300 images, I get the following error:

```
[1]    12202 bus error  node index.js
```

I have tried to set `sharp.cache(false)`, but that has not worked. Any idea how to solve it? I suppose I'm getting some overflow, but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Probably a stack overflow. I would compose in chunks of ~2,000 images at once.

Comment: 2000? It dies in the same way with 300 xdd

Comment: Oh heh, not that then. I would ask on the sharp issue tracker https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues -- Lovell is very helpful. I tried a test program in python using pyvips and that drew 2000 pins in a couple of seconds and a few 100 mb of memory, so I don't think you're seeing a libvips issue.

Comment: done! https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2896 Thanks for the info! :)